# Mysql query to get count per months

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a table for my users that have a field named "created" that have the registration date.

How can i get a list that contains a count for the registrations number per month in last 12 months?
Like this:

```
Month   Count
1        1232
2        2222
3         122
4        4653
...       ...
12       7654
```

I'm not used to working with mysql, so until now i just know how to count the number of registrations in last year, not how to group that count by last 12 months. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Now I'm getting this, using @fthiella solution:

```
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
| Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) | Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) | Count(*) |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
|                         2012 |                             4 |     9927 |
|                         2012 |                             5 |     5595 |
|                         2012 |                             6 |     4431 |
|                         2012 |                             7 |     3299 |
|                         2012 |                             8 |      429 |
|                         2012 |                            10 |     3698 |
|                         2012 |                            11 |     6208 |
|                         2012 |                            12 |     5142 |
|                         2013 |                             1 |     1196 |
|                         2013 |                             2 |       10 |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+
```

How can i force query to give me the months with count = 0?

Solution by @fthiella (thanks a lot!):

```
     SELECT y, m, Count(users.created)
     FROM (
      SELECT y, m
      FROM
         (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
         (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
           UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
           UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
       LEFT JOIN users
       ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.created))
          AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.created))
     WHERE
       (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
       OR
       (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
     GROUP BY y, m;
```

And the results:

```
+------+----+----------------------+
| y    | m  | Count(users.created) |
+------+----+----------------------+
| 2012 |  5 |                 5595 |
| 2012 |  6 |                 4431 |
| 2012 |  7 |                 3299 |
| 2012 |  8 |                  429 |
| 2012 |  9 |                    0 |
| 2012 | 10 |                 3698 |
| 2012 | 11 |                 6208 |
| 2012 | 12 |                 5142 |
| 2013 |  1 |                 1196 |
| 2013 |  2 |                   10 |
| 2013 |  3 |                    0 |
| 2013 |  4 |                    0 |
+------+----+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If created is an INT field, you should use [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert it to a date field, and then [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function to extract the month:

```
SELECT Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), Count(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
```

this will count all the rows that have been created in the last 12 months. Please notice that it's probably better to also group by the YEAR:

```
SELECT Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), Count(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
```

If you need to count the registration numbers instead of the rows, you could use something like

```
COUNT(registration_number)
```

to skip null values, or

```
COUNT(DISTINCT registration_number)
```

to count only distinct ones.

**Edit**

If you also need to show months that have count=0, I would use a query like this that returns all of the months for the current and for the previous year:

```
SELECT y, m
FROM
  (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
  (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
    UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months;
```

And then I'd use a LEFT JOIN, that returns all of the rows of the first query, and only the rows of the second query that matches:

```
SELECT y, m, Count(yourtable.created)
FROM (
  SELECT y, m
  FROM
    (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
    (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
  LEFT JOIN yourtable
  ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created))
     AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created))
WHERE
  (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
  OR
  (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
GROUP BY y, m
```

(please notice that here I am considering just the last 12 months, so if we are in the middle April 2013 it will count rows in the interval May 2012 - April 13, if this is not the correct behaviour please let me know)

Comment: my created field is an int field because my registration date is in timestamp format...

Comment: @fthiella, How can i force query to give me the months with count = 0?

Comment: @DavidR i updated my answer, in this particular situation it complicates things a little...please let me know if it's okay

Comment: @fthiella Is it possible to make your answer for all years? Because your answer only covers a 12-month period. But is it possible if I wanted to do it for all years, if possible, what kind of changes should you make in your codes? Like started at 2014

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT MONTH(reg_date) , COUNT(reg_date) 
FROM your_table
WHERE reg_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY MONTH(reg_date)
```

Comment: Its showing for the MOnths whose records are available in Database. How would I do it for all month. Means from 1-12 months. ??

Comment: Check the other answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps anyone else, I additionally wanted this query but for a given time interval that was not necessarily the last 12 months (also with a timestamp for the date):

```
set @start='2013-05-01 00:00:00';
set @end='2015-03-31 00:00:00';

SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date)), COUNT(yourtable.created_date) 
FROM yourtable
WHERE created_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE(@start) ) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE(@end) )
GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date))
ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtable.created_date));
```