# GroupBy clause incrementing date in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I wish to create simple monthly report method of records created in particular month. Now I wish to add days dynamically using query only. I don't wish to fetch result first and parse according to any other language.

Suppose my reports is of 30 days of current month. But I have records correspondingly of only few dates. I need to include days whose corresponding days are not available in Database.

MySQL Query that I tried. I hope it would create Dates dynamically.

```
SELECT (COUNT(`Song`.`id`)) AS `Song__daily`, (dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, created))) AS `Song__dateCreate` 
FROM `demosite_trial`.`tbl_songs` AS `Song` 
WHERE `Song`.`deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(DAY, 0, created))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql query to get count per months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774280/mysql-query-to-get-count-per-months)

Comment: No its not. I am asking specifically for MySQL DB and its specific to day of month. Not year or month.