# SQL sum aggregate including 0

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. One is an employee table containing the employee information and the other table is the sales the employee has made. I am trying to group the sum of sales made by an employee in a month including the months where he/she has made zero sales. Here are some of the values in the table

**Employees table**

```
number             name
1                  Matt
2                  Foggy
3                  Karen
4                  Wilson
```

**sales**

```
employee_number           month          sale_number          sale_amount
1                         January 2015       1                    300
1                         January 2015       2                     50
1                         February 2015      1                     400
2                         March 2015         1                     300
3                         January 2015       1                     50
```

I was able to write the query for getting the *monthly sales sum* using the following query

`select sum(sales.sale_amount), sales.employee_number, sales.month, sales.sale_number 
    from sales group by employee_number, month;`

Now because I also need the months including zeros I thought left outer join with the different months should do the trick. However the output still consists of the same output from before without zeros or null. Does the left outer join not join the null values?

The output should be something like this.

`number                name        sale_amount             sale_month
1                      Matt         350                     January 2015
1                      Matt         400                     February 2015
1                      Matt         0                       March 2015
2                      Foggy        0                       January 2015
2                      Foggy        0                       February 2015
2                      Foggy        300                     March 2015`

and so on.

Comment: Also I apologize for not having the proper format. this is my first question here

Comment: Welcome to SO. Provide desired output.

Comment: First choose one `Mysql` or `Sql Server` both are two different database

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774280/mysql-query-to-get-count-per-months).

Comment: Sorry, edited and now also put in the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `left outer join` conjures up `null` values for missing rows from the **right hand** table.  To show all months, you'd switch the order of tables:

```
from    months
cross join
        employees
left outer join 
        sales 
on      sales.month = months.month
        and employees.number = sales.employee_number
```

If you're missing a months table, you can ad-lib one from the sales table:

```
select  months.month
,       employees.name
,       sum(sale_amount) as sales
from    (
        select  distinct month
        from    sales
        ) as months
cross join
        employees
left outer join 
        sales 
on      sales.month = months.month
        and employees.number = sales.employee_number
group by
        months.month
,       employees.name
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c42aa/4/0)

Comment: This would only work if I had a separate months table right?

Comment: @HarryGohil months table with exactly with same data like `January 2015 , February 2015..` but i would suggest you to keep date values with date datatype in months table and sales table.

Comment: @Andomar Awesome logic with the cross join and then the left join. I believe that should do the trick:). The second query however does not seem to be working for me. It gives me an incorrect syntax error for line 1.

Comment: Pretty sure the second query should work?  Can you reproduce the problem at http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Yea sqlfiddle game me the same problem. Here's the link  - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c42aa/2

Comment: Hmmm... I was just outlining the solution, here's [a fully expanded version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c42aa/4/0)...

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. This one works as I wanted it to.  If you don't mind, I'll add it to the original question so that people can use it in the future if needed.

Comment: It's better if the answer is in the answer section :)  I've moved it now and included the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Following query will help you:

```
SELECT q1.month, q1.number, q2.total_sales FROM
    (SELECT distinct s.month, e.number 
        FROM sales s, Employees e) AS q1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(sales.sale_amount) AS total_sales, sales.employee_number, sales.month, sales.sale_number 
        FROM sales group by employee_number, month) AS q2
    ON (q1.month = q2.month) AND (q1.number = q2.employee_number) 
ORDER BY month, number;
```

check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79ae7/1)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick - using pre-1992 style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Thanks a lot !This one works for me as well. But @Andomar provided a really good solution too:)