# A Database Error Occurred in counting all results method using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently doing a event scheduling module for my system. I want to count all the scheduled events for all months.. For example I have 10 events for this march, then 5 incoming events in April but I am encountering error "A Database Error Occurred" 
[image: Error message]
**CONTROLLER**

```
$data['getAll'] = $this->CrudModel->count_all('events');
```

**MODEL**

```
public function count_all($table)

    {
        // $this->db->select('service');
        // $this->db->from($table);
        // $this->db->where('date LIKE','%'.$month.'%'); // 2017-03-04
        // $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
        // return $num_results->result();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT date, service from $table");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            # code...
            $date = $row->date;
            $service = $row->service;
            $date_explode = explode('-', $date);
            $year = $date_explode[0];
            $month   = $date_explode[1];
            $day  = $date_explode[2];
            $service_explode = explode(',', $service);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($date_explode);
            print_r($service_explode);
            echo "</pre>";
            $this->db->like('date',$month); // 2017-03-04
            $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
        }
        // return $query->result();
    }
```

Question: Is my query wrong? If yes what is it? Or any other suggestion how to count all the scheduled events?

NOTE: I only used one date.. The scheduled date(Eg. I scheduled the event in 2017-03-04), i dont have end date(cause I used the date input type in html)

Comment: Looks like [this answer would work.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15774329/3585500)

Comment: In the first query  there is error.query will be `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT date, service from '$table' "); ` **single inverted comma** on $table

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the query is missing a `FROM` clause and tablename. (Or an inline view query in place of an identifier.)

MySQL (or MariaDB) Server is reporting a syntax error, flagging the the `WHERE` keyword. MySQL is expecting the statement to have `FROM` clause, and is not finding it.

---

The error message reports that an invalid statement was issued, looks like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` WHERE ...
```

What's missing is the `FROM` keyword and a table_name:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS `minimums` FROM some_row_source WHERE ...
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Maybe `$table` is being evaluated as an empty string?

For debugging this, I'd suggest first figuring out which line(s) of code is causing this SQL statement to be executed.

Comment: I got the $table in my controller.. I used the parameter to pass it to my model.

Comment: And I also tried to print $table, it display my table named events

Answer (score 0):

you must specify table name

```
$this->db->count_all_results("table");
```

[Active Record Documentation for count_all_results();](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Sir, sorry for the late reply.. In my controller I defined my table in there then I used it to passed to the parameter in my CrudModel and when I check the $table in my model.. It displayed my events table