# How to get last 12 months user login data by per month in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get user login activity per month and then to show it in statistic in a bar chat. But the problem i am facing is that its not giving me any data. I will share my code first it will easier to explain my problem

My LoginActivity Model

```
class LogActivity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'laravel_logger_activity';

    public function logActivity(){
        $videoPerMonth = array();

        for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
            $age= 12 - $i;
            $userPerMonth[$i] = count(LogActivity::whereNotIn('userId', [1])->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('n') -$age)->get());

        }
     }
    }
```

In this i do get user's activity per month but this is not accurate because being the first month if u subtract 12 value goes to negative. And i dont get actual reults.
So, after reading few articles i changed my code to this

```
$userPerMonth =count( LogActivity::whereNotIn('userId', [1])->whereMonth('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(12))->get());
return json_encode($userPerMonth);
```

But this returns empty.What shall i do ?

I want to get data by month vs activity 
For example nov 2017 : 300 , dec 2017:800,jan 01 2018:100 
Something like that so i can put in bar chat 
Can anyone please help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to tackle this in a different way, instead of trying to get the user's login activity per month in a loop. I would get the user's login activity for a date range such as a year. This would result in one SQL query being run rather than 12 per user. Once you have the data you can loop through the results and sort them into an array or collection.

Or you could do it as the equivalent of this SQL statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m') as login_month, user_id
FROM login_tokens
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01 00:00:01' AND created_at <= '2017-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY user_id, login_month
```

I think to do this in eloquent you would need to do the following;

```
$logActivity = LogActivity::where(‘created_at’, ‘>=’, ‘2017-01-01 00:00:01’)
                            ->where(‘created’, ‘<=’, ’23:59:59’)
                            ->select(\DB:raw(‘COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m') as login_month, user_id’))
                            ->groupBy(‘user_id’)
                            ->groupBy(‘login_month’)
                            ->get();
```

Downside to this approach is you're having to put in knowledge of the SQL language, which could differ from MySql, to SQLite, MSSQL etc.

A useful tip if you remove the `get()` and replace it with `toSql()` you can echo out the query.

```
echo LogActivity::where(‘created_at’, ‘>=’, ‘2017-01-01 00:00:01’)
                  ->where(‘created’, ‘<=’, ’23:59:59’)
                  ->select(\DB:raw(‘COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m') as login_month, user_id’))
                  ->groupBy(‘user_id’)
                  ->groupBy(‘login_month’)
                  ->toSql();
dd();
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: I tried this `$logActivity = LoginActivity::where('created_at', '>=', '2017-01-01 00:00:01')
                            ->where('created_at', '<=', '23:59:59')
                            ->select(\DB::raw('COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") as login_month, userId'))
                            ->groupBy('userId')
                            ->groupBy('login_month')
                            ->get(); `

It returned empty array

Comment: I think i have the same as this one but i have no clue what he did and how to convert into eloquent .
 If you can take a look and somehow explain it to me i would appreciate.
 [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774280/mysql-query-to-get-count-per-months?rq=1

Comment: @user7747472 did you try `->toSql()` instead of the `get()`? 

If so what was the SQL output?

Comment: sorry for replying so late.
and yes i tried that here is the output  `select COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") as login_month, userId from 'laravel_logger_activity' where 'created_at' >= ? and 'created_at' <= ? group by 'userId', 'login_month' `

Comment: @user7747472 have you then taken that SQL statement and tried running it in something like Sequel Pro, HeidiSQL, MySQL workbench, NaviCat?

That should tell you if there's an issue with your query, obviously you'll need to replace the question marks with actual dates. From a glance, the query won't work with the single quotes ' around the table name. It would either have to be nothing or a back tick `. 

Also, your user id is camelcased, but all the other columns are snake_cased which is a bit usual.

Comment: @user7747472 I can't seem to comment on your post. If you're wanting to sort by the year as well you'll need to return the year with the data set from the database. In your foreach for the months you're always forcing the year in the mktime. Personally, I would avoid that foreach because you would be limiting yourself to only getting data out for 12 months.For example, if you wanted to select 2012 - 2018, you wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Yes i understand your point , the reason i want to get only last 12 months is only to show user activity graph on the admin dashboard.

Comment: @user7747472 added on another answer for you, hope this helps :-)

Comment: hey, your answer is amazing the query u gave is awesome too. It took me a while to understand the statement you gave. But with your answer i finially achieved the target after long 4 months i guess . :P

Comment: Here is what i added to your query


`$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("-12 Months"));
            $to= Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
            $data['activity'] =LogActivity::where('created_at', '>=', $from)
                ->where('created_at', '<=', $to)
                ->orderBy('created_at')
               ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, \'%M %Y \') as login_month'))
//                            ->groupBy('login_month')
                ->get()->toArray();  `

Answer (score 1):

I've knocked together a simple class that is more or less what I think you're after. Please note that the use statements are probably not quite right and I've not run this code, so use it as an example. Basically what I've done here is get the current date and work out the previous year from now.

That is then used to select the data from the database within `getActivity` method. An empty array is created `$dateRange` for storing the results in with the keys being the year and the month i.e. 2018-02, 2018-01, 2017-12, 2017-11 and so on.

Next I'm doing a simple check to see if we actually have any results from the database because if there are no results then the logins would be 0 for each month.

Then get a date range, okay I've swapped back to standard PHP date interval here as I don't know the Carbon syntax of the top of my head, but as Carbon extends PHP's DateTime it probably should work. However, it may need some tweaking here as well. So get the date range between the two dates by a monthly interval.

Then loop through this date range, use the `$hasLoginActivity` variable we defined earlier and if that's false add the date range formatted to year-month as the key and the value to zero.

If we have results then add the date range with the same formatting and get the data from the results. As we have returned a collection from Laravel's ORM we should be able to where on it again, [see Collections docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where). Store this to a variable and check to see if we have results before trying to access the property, else set to zero. You might be able to skip this and access it like `$loginActivity->where('login_year_month', $date->format('Y-m'))->login_num;` but I can't remember of the top of my head if this causes an error trying to access property on a null value.

I hope this helps.

```
    <?php 

use Carbon;
use DateInterval;
use DatePeriod;
use LogActivity as LogActivityModel;

class LogActivity 
{
    public function annualActivity(): array
    {
        // Get the current date/time and get a year from now.
        $now = new Carbon();        
        $aYearAgo = $now->clone()->subYears(1);

        // Get any login activity from the last year to now.
        $loginActivity = $this->getActivity($aYearAgo, $now);

        $dateRange = [];

        $hasLoginActvity = $loginActivity->count();

        // Get a date range from a year ago to now and loop through them.
        foreach ($this->getDateRange($aYearAgo, $now) as $date) {
            // If we there were no results, then just create the array with a result set of zero.
            if (! $hasLoginActvity) {
                $dateRange[$date->format('Y-m')] = 0;
                continue;
            } 

            $monthActivity = $loginActivity->where('login_year_month', $date->format('Y-m'));

            $loginCount = $monthActivity ? $monthActivity->login-num : 0;

            // Add to the array the date YYYY-MM as the key i.e. 2018-02 and search the collection for the same date.
            $dateRange[$date->format('Y-m')] = $loginCount;
        }        

        // Return the array date with the year and month as the key and a integer as the value.   
        return $dateRange;    
    }

    private function getActivity(Carbon $aYearAgo, Carbon $now)
    {
        return LogActivityModel::where(‘created_at’, ‘>=’, $aYearAgo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
          ->where(‘created_at’, ‘<=’, $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
          ->select(\DB:raw(‘COUNT(*) as login_num, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m') as login_year_month, user_id’))
          ->groupBy(‘user_id’)
          ->groupBy(‘login_month’)
          ->all();
    }

    private function getDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        // Get a the date range between the two dates with an interval of a month.
        return new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1M') ,$to);
    }
}
```